# Verify third party finger print - xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to develop a xamarin.forms app for employee clock In .When user clock in, I can get the finger print data of that user stored in database through API. Can we compare the fetched finger print against users fingerprint when they apply their finger against phones scanner? I know we can authenticate against phones enrolled fingerprint. Is it possible to authenticate with applied finger print against fetched finger print in xamarin ? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You can not get the actual fingerprint scan data from iOS or Android (assuming the device even has a fingerprint sensor installed). You would need to authenticate the user (and thus their device) via another method (like O-Auth2) to a service that is linked to your fingerprint database.

Comment: i.e. The user logs in once via your app and the OAuth token is stored on the device in secure storage, the app then uses the biometric API (Android and/or iOS) to allow entry into the app, the oauth token is compared to the server (seach for "OAuth2 server flow"), if still valid (i.e. does not need refreshed or is not revoked), the user **identify** is confirmed since they provided the biometric unlock, then your app performs some function at that point. (This is the same basic process that mobile banking apps are doing)

Comment: @SushiHangover Sir, In my app, initially several employees are listed. I will place the app on a device in the company. Employees can come and select their profile and verify using their fingerprint. Is it possible using the Token method?

Comment: Are you talking about a single device (phone?) that multiple people use? If so, that will not work as iOS/Android do not allow an unlimited number of biometric registrations. You would need to use an external fingerprint scanner (there are 3rd-party USB-OTG fingerprint readers that have their own SDK) and code your app against their product.

Comment: @SushiHangover Oh okey sir. In my case i dont want the fingerprint data stored in device. Simply want to compare the API finger print data to the live finger print. So its not possible. right sir?

Comment: Unless you are using an external fingerprint scanner so multiple people can use a single device, then no, you can not use the phone's built-in fingerprint sensor to identify multiple people. There are dedicate Android-power devices that do have fingerprint "identity scanners" housed in the same physical unit (they are sold for use in areas like time recording, much like the dedicated Android devices that have barcode reader "built-in" used for inventory or POS system)